# Setting up JAX-RS to provide an API and serve up static resources

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, embedded-jetty

Let me me first explain my requirements.
I'm trying to build a JAX-RS application with embedded jetty server to serve up:

```
/    => Single Page Application (static index.html, JS, images )

/api => Driving API (JAX-RS resources)
```

The problem I've been having is that **not** with the API, but rather the static resources. My current configuration is this:

> ```
> public static void main( final String[] args ) throws Exception
> {
>     // create our server on port 4567
>     final Server server = new Server( 4567 );
>
>     // create a default context handler for our server to root path with sessions enabled
>     final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler( ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS );
>     // our root static path
>
>     // create container for JAX-RS servlet resources mapped with configuration
>     final ServletContainer servletContainer = new ServletContainer( new MyConfig() );
>     // create our servlet holder for our multiple JAX-RS resources
>     final ServletHolder apiServletHolder = new ServletHolder( servletContainer );
>     // map our JAX-RS resources to begin at root route
>     context.addServlet( apiServletHolder, "/api/*" );
>
>     final ServletHolder staticServlet = new ServletHolder( new DefaultServlet() );
>     staticServlet.setInitParameter( 
>         "resourceBase", Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource( "." ).toString() );
>     context.addServlet( staticServlet, "/" );
>
>     server.setHandler( context );
>     server.start();
>     server.join();
> }
> ```

My folder configuration is as follows:

```
├───main
│   ├───java
│   │   └───com
│   │       └───bar
│   │           └───foo
│   │               └───controllers
│   └───static
│       └───images
└───test
    └───java
        └───com
            └───bar
                └───foo
```

My POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>jettyApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jettyApp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-jetty-http</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.bar.foo.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>com.foo.bar.Main</Main-Class>
                                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                                        <Build-Number>123</Build-Number>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jetty.version>9.3.0.M2</jetty.version>
        <jersey.version>2.7</jersey.version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

When I create a jar with shade though, the application fails as the location of the static resources display the folder that I'm running the application from:

```
$ pwd
/home/workspace/example
$ java -jar example.jar
# server starts
$ curl localhost:4567
# tree of /home/workspace/example
```

This is no doubt due to setting the resource base in Main.class.

**My Question:**

**How do I package this and configure this in a way that it works for both IDE and standalone uber jar?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please dont ask for direct code. Show your initial efforts and ask for directions....why you need POM, try to create maven project and build upon it to generate standalone jar...

Comment: Try to setup static servlet before api handler.